# How can you persist a single authenticated requests session in python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the python `requests` library to intereact with an api.

I am first authenticating, getting a `session-id` and then creating a request `session` to persist that connection.

So I created a class to do this, but every time I use the class I am reinitialising and doing the authentication again. Which I want to avoid.
Essentially I created an API between the API I am calling using DRF.
How can I ensure that only 1 authenticated session is used across the entire app and that it persists through multiple request?

The class:

```
class RestClient:

    session = None

    def create_rest_client(self):
        auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(
            USERNAME,
            PASSWORD
        )
        response = requests.post(
            f'https://{ settings.HOST }/rest/session',
            auth=auth
        )

        session = requests.Session()
        session_id = response.json().get('value')
        session.headers.update({'api-session-id': session_id})

        return session

    def get_rest_client(self):
        if self.session:
            return self.session
        else:
            return self.create_rest_client()
```

Using the class I instantiate and get the client (naturally redoing the auth). I think this should either be global or a singleton.

Using class:

```
class ProductDetail(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None, **kwargs):
        response = []

        rest_client = RestClient()
        session = rest_client.get_rest_client()

        response = session.get(
            ....use authenticated session
        )

        return Response(response.json())
```

Comment: Any reason you're don't store the `session` on an instance of a `RestClient` object and just pass that instance around where needed?

Comment: You might also want to consider creating a custom class that inherits from `requests.Session` and override the `__init__` accordingly to make the initial request to update its own headers... then just pass that object around and treat it as though it was any other `requests.Session` object...

Comment: Ah that sounds good. I updated the usage in the quesitons to show I am doing this in response to a call to my api. I'm just not sure on the `pass the object around` bit. Could you give an example?

Comment: Have you looked at how Django manages its establishing a DB connection just once that's available throughout the entire framework? I believe re-reading your question that's the sort of thing you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd wire up a property like this:

```py
class RestClient:
    _session = None

    @property
    def session(self):
        if self._session:
            return self._session

        auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        response = requests.post(
            f"https://{ settings.HOST }/rest/session", auth=auth
        )

        session = requests.Session()
        session_id = response.json().get("value")
        session.headers.update({"api-session-id": session_id})

        self._session = session
        return session
```

Now you can simply do `client.session` and it will be set up on the first access and reused thereafter.

*EDIT:* To persist this *between* `RestClient` instances, change references to `self._session` to `RestClient._session`.

Comment: That neatened it up real nice, thanks. Although, it doesn't persist as every time I use it, it has to authenticate again.

Comment: If you create the `client` object once, it should persist.

Comment: Added an edit about persisting it as a class variable.

Comment: `self` refers to the instance of `RestClient` you instantiate with `RestClient()`; `RestClient` refers to the class `RestClient`. Setting an attribute (`_session`) on the class object is, well, it's practically a global, but namespaced into the class.

Comment: Hmmm starting to think this might not be the solution, as when the session expires its breaking my app. So I need a mechanism of checking that the session is there and also not expired.

Comment: When the session expires, you can refresh it with `RestClient._session = None`, so the next call to `.session` will get a new one with a new token. It may also be worth it to subclass `requests.Session` itself and add this automatic refresh in the `.request()` method.